# How do I access Windows server on a Microsoft Azure Website?

Tags: https, windows, azure

I need to generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) on my Microsoft Azure website in order to get an SSL certificate. I'm attempting to follow [this tutorial](https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-ssl-installation-windows-azure-website.htm).

Step 1.1 says,

> On your Windows server, download and save the DigiCert® Certificate Utility for Windows executable (DigiCertUtil.exe).

How do I access Windows server on my Azure website in order to download and save the utility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an Azure website not running in a VPS, you just need to supply a .pfx file ([this step](https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-ssl-installation-windows-azure-website.htm#configure_ssl_for_site) of the tutorial).

You can use the Utility running on any Windows machine (including your local workstation) to create the .pfx file as described in the tutorial.